# MySQL PHP alter table, change all MEDIUMINT to INT

Tags: php, mysql, database

In the past I've used a PHP script to change the language of all fields, but I can't find anything for switching all UNSIGNED MEDIUMINT to UNSIGNED INT. Is this possible? Should I manually switch them all? :o

Turns out mediumint is too small... so I have to change a lot of fields /:

edit:
thanks for the input, I might just do it manually now that I know there's no simple automated way of doing it. I just didn't want to waste my time changing 100+ fields manually if there was an automated way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL does not have an automated way to say "take all of the columns of type X and change them to type Y."  You may be able to query the `information_schema` database to figure out which columns you need to alter, and then you can build the `ALTER TABLE` query based on that information.

Specifically, have a look at the `information_schema.columns` table.

Comment: Using this plus PHP logic, I should be able to write a script to change all fields of type x to type y, right? I think it might be a little quicker to do it manually though, haha.

Comment: Yes, you could definitely do this.  The reason that I didn't provide some sample code is because it will probably take at least 10-15 minutes of research, and... yeah... it will probably take you less to look at the schema and write a set of `ALTER TABLE` queries by hand.  :)  Laziness is the chief virtue of programmers, but there comes a point when it's harder to tell the computer how to do the work than it is to do it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below query to find all `mediumint` columns (with respective table names) in a specific database and then iterate over the results to generate and execute `ALTER` queries in your choice of programming language.

```
SELECT 
    table_name, column_name, numeric_precision, column_type
FROM
    information_schema.columns
WHERE
    TABLE_SCHEMA = 'DATABASE_NAME'
        AND data_type = 'mediumint';
```

Answer (score 0):

Has to be done in SQL, so if it makes sense in your case to write a script to do it, go for it, but most likely you will want to do it manually.

Since you are going from a data type that is less descriptive to a data type that is more descriptive, you should be fine.

Usint the [ALTER TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/alter-table.html) Syntax should work:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY column_name INT UNSIGNED
```